# Video Element doesn't load due to duplicate requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, video

My webApp (written in HTML5 and jQuery) contains a video element, who's source is dynamically assigned after user interaction.
After the source (video element path, not source tag) is added, I call video-element.load(), and for some reason two GET requests are sent to my localhost server.
The first request has Range header of

```
bytes=0-
```

and the second

```
bytes=<FileLength>-
```

My server (written in C#) takes both requests and serves them (sending back a mp4 file in one "big" chunk). But the video elements seems empty (blank), and won't respond to .play().

My biggest problem is that this problem is not consistent, it might not happen with a file, and then it will, about a second later. Also, it's happens to me only on Chrome V52 and above (doesn't happen on V51, or Firefox for example)

Anybody has any thought?
How can I check if it's an HTML problem? A JS problem? Is the browser supposed to send 2 GET requests even do I call load() once?

Comment: whats the event that triggers loading the data?

Comment: A click event on some div, checked it though and no GET request is sent prior to load(), and then there are 2 at once (if that's where you're going)

Comment: so obviously the event bubbles and fires two times?

Comment: If I understood what you meant then no, load is reached once (Checked with a breakpoint in chrome-dev-tools). Also, notice that I updated that it only happens in chrome, and so, if you mean that load is called twice, it should have called twice in other browsers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate solution to your problem would be to change your web server, to make it able to deal with such requests.
The options are:
1. Fix it to support answering with partial response chunks (using the response header Content-Range)
2. Configure it to disable partial response altogether (by adding Accept-Ranges:none to the response headers